# Where should I put ASP.NET Core Runtime binaries?

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, .net-core, runtime

Some example code I'm playing with informs me that I need ASP.NET Core Runtime 2.1.14. I found it [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1). I'm on macOS and there is no installer, so I downloaded the "binaries" at the link "x64" under the heading "ASP.NET Core Runtime 2.1.14" on the right. I extracted the compressed folder, called "aspnetcore-runtime-2.1.14-osx-x64", which has the following contents:

```
dotnet
host
LICENSE.txt
shared
ThirdPartyNotices.txt
```

Now, I haven't the foggiest idea what I should do with these to install ASP.NET Core Runtime 2.1.14. Could someone please tell me what I should do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To build and run ASP.NET Core apps on macOS, you need to install the SDK which also contains the runtime. There's an installer for that on the page you linked.

You can check the installed SDKs using `dotnet --list-sdks` and see where are they located. Same goes for the runtimes with `dotnet --list-runtimes`. The .NET CLI chooses the SDK version for each `dotnet` command, so in your case it will pick the one compatible with the version specified in your project. By default, it would use the latest.

Answer (score 3):

There is an installer for MacOS on the [download page for 2.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1) you visited:

[image]

Make sure to download the **SDK** (it includes the Runtime) in the column **Installers**, not Binaries.

Then install it as any MacOS application. Once you did it, you can type `dotnet --version` in a terminal and it will return the version you just installed.